# How to get a multidimentional array of all products of two vectors in R?

Tags: r, arrays, multidimensional-array, multiplication

Is there a method that will take `c(2, 3, 5)` and `c(7, 11)` and and give me all element-wise products as an array?:

```
14 22
21 33
35 55
```

Bonus points if it can take more than two vectors or if it can take arrays as well as vectors (like take a 4D array, a 5D array, and a 6D array, and give me a 15D array as an output).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given two vectors `a` and `b`, we can use `outer` once:

```
mat <- outer(a, b)
```

The result is a matrix, with `mat[i, j]` for `a[i] * b[j]`.

---

For more than two vectors, say `a`, `b` and `c` stored in a list, we iteratively apply `outer`:

```
arr <- Reduce("outer", list(a, b, c))
```

The result is a high-dimensional array, with `arr[i, j, k]` for `a[i] * b[j] * c[k]`.

Answer (score 0):

- We can use

```
t(sapply(x , \(x) x * matrix(y , ncol = 2)))
```

- Output

```
    [,1] [,2]
[1,]   14   22
[2,]   21   33
[3,]   35   55
```

- Data

```
x <- c(2, 3, 5)
y <- c(7, 11)
```